# Using PhoneGap Media() function on the web

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

When using phonegap I'm forced to use their Media library to play sounds on Android. That works so now I want to use their library for everything.

Can I just upload cordova.js and media.js to my server so that I can use their media library when the user is on a computer?

I don't know which js files I need or from what type of build I can steal them. Can phonegap make a build for the web?

The whole point is to not have separate code for separate platforms so this should be supported right?

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap/Cordova works by providing a javascript component, which defines the api you interact with when writing your app, and a native component.

If you grab the cordova.js and media.js from your mobile project and upload to your server, it would be missing the correct native hooks to actually call down into the native commands.

Check out [Cordova Windows](https://github.com/apache/cordova-windows) and [Cordova OSX](https://github.com/apache/cordova-osx) and [Cordova Ubuntu](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ubuntu)

These are versions of cordova targeting desktop platforms, their compatibility will depend on what OS your server is running.